# Need to skip a value from writing to report

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a macro to pull some values from a database,  but I need it to skip the write to report if the `value =(x)`.

Basically if my object string is equal to 0019, 0057, or , 0064 then I don't want it to write to my excel document.

Any ideas?

Comment: Control flow? So, If statements or Select Case? http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/top-ten-excel-vba-control-structures.html

Comment: if you want to exclude the results from the data pull, you'll need to do that in the query. If you want to exclude the results once the data is in Excel there's all kinds of ways to do that.

Comment: (this was meant to be an edit of my previous comment)So either you'll need to only pull the data you want to show up in Excel, or you could always create an IF statement when writing data into Excel. For instance, if I pulled a bunch of data and was pasting it with Range().Value = data, I could simply put an If Not data = "0019" Then Range().Value = data

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guys thanks for the suggestion, I ended up setting my IF statements to not equal to those 3 values and write to report everything else.